# Google drive v3 REST API returns max of 460 records

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I was exploring the usage of google drive v3 REST api in libcurl in C. Here I was always getting only the 460 records of 1000 max page size for the below query. But, I have 3000+ files in the directory that I was fetching. So, this will increase the number of iteration in the code.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,modifiedTime,webViewLink,mimeType,fileExtension,size,hasThumbnail,thumbnailLink,trashed,shared,parents,md5Checksum,ownedByMe,version,starred,kind,owners(emailAddress))&pageSize=1000&pageToken=PAGE_TOKEN&q=parents=PARENT_ID
```

Please help me to resolve this behaviour, is there any other limitations exist for max page size that fixed by google ?

Comment: I think that your search query of `q=parents=PARENT_ID` is not correct. In this case, the search query is required to be `'folderId' in parents`. So at your URL including the query parameters, the error of `Invalid Value` at location `q` occurs. But you say `Here I was always getting only the 460 records of 1000 max page size for the below query.`. So I thought that your actual URL including the query parameters might be different from that in your question. How about this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here I was not getting any error. Pasted below the actual working query from the code. ```https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,modifiedTime,webViewLink,mimeType,fileExtension,size,hasThumbnail,thumbnailLink,trashed,shared,parents,md5Checksum,ownedByMe,version,starred,kind,owners(emailAddress))&pageSize=1000&pageToken=PAGE_TOKEN&q=parents='1_m7AipvwhKayhy6awYETqJYnp51vU_I1'+and+trashed=false```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, the search query of your replying is also not correct. When you want to retrieve the file list in the specific folder, please use `'folderId' in parents`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) How about this?

Comment: This is the one we are interesting right ? correct me if I wrong. 
*Search for the ID 1234567 in the parents collection. This finds all files and folders located directly in the folder whose ID is 1234567.*

```'1234567' in parents```

Comment: Yes. I think that your understanding is correct. And now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect it. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Please mind that the request URL must be URL encoded

It should look as following wihtout a `nextPageToken`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=%271_m7AipvwhKayhy6awYETqJYnp51vU_I1%27%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2Cname%2CcreatedTime%2CmodifiedTime%2CwebViewLink%2CmimeType%2CfileExtension%2Csize%2ChasThumbnail%2CthumbnailLink%2Ctrashed%2Cshared%2Cparents%2Cmd5Checksum%2CownedByMe%2Cversion%2Cstarred%2Ckind%2Cowners(emailAddress))&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \`

and similar to this with a `nextPageToken`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1&pageToken=~!!~AI9FV7QgekoKZ7DYm0LKX3BwSw_2PKij-dmfvT5pEBNHwRB0eJVtU4_Pgx2dozBduQsq0QGtzEKIplJOECYIlfzLjxpS_b0b-InrFQ2fl6WvHR9C9Uc4TsYb1G3nRo0GbZdQlgrkOink-AIlNs4aJccn3OoXrs85YBNbIl8AP9u-C_2pIfIIjj1_hMao3DRRT98f9DNObooDp-zf5ud159JtD1hyRKZdrBdNmMkRXDCE2e64BQbSZ5Yais7XScATZo3OqRwBhTYmSPQXbjSkICiIYPytfLDd8pwH-yC_yjUM1DwomszqJYbGFmLmnd5LheafrUVExo6ypx9vtyADiW5Qc7KuCGwgXrkZLlJy_1n8h6y4h6ksYbiao7mXcqxzhzzc0Fk9b8Y9vJ5k81iZVZcJ9gUjz6YQQQ%3D%3D&q=%271_m7AipvwhKayhy6awYETqJYnp51vU_I1%27%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(id%2Cname%2CcreatedTime%2CmodifiedTime%2CwebViewLink%2CmimeType%2CfileExtension%2Csize%2ChasThumbnail%2CthumbnailLink%2Ctrashed%2Cshared%2Cparents%2Cmd5Checksum%2CownedByMe%2Cversion%2Cstarred%2Ckind%2Cowners(emailAddress))&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \`

**Also mind that to retrieve the first page you should not provide a `nextPageToken`.**

- If you expect more than 3000 results, but receive only 460 - it is likely that you provide the `nextPageToken` for the 4rth page and thus get the last 460 of 340 results.
- If you do obtain only 460 results without providing a `nextPageToken` (so for the first page) - this means that there are indeed only 460 results that satisfy your query - doublecheck if the query is correct.

Comment: Yes, I taken care of the points that you are mentioned.

Comment: I have tried the suggested google drive rest query in postman tool, oauth playground and also in libcurl. 
I was getting the 1000 items by reducing the number of fields that mentioned here. If I increase the fields, again the count get reduced to 460. Is this because of any size limitations set by google in data transfer on each request ?
Query:```https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q='1GV_qAYwU-HYQNeBHcECWfFnaew' in parents and trashed = false&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,mimeType,size,hasThumbnail,trashed)```

Comment: I recommend you to try your request with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to see if it results in the same behavior.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. By fields, do you mean the fields you are retrieving as a result or the query parameter you specify. Test which field in specific causes your issue.

Comment: Just I tried and getting the same item counts (460). But with the less number of fields again it results 1000 items. Is there any bug or limitation in googleapis ?

For the below query getting only 93 items
 ```https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=%271GV_qAYwU-HYQNeBHcECWfFnaew%27%20in%20parents%20and%20trashed%20%3D%20false&fields=nextPageToken%2Cfiles(*)&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]```

Comment: Issue is not specifically with the fields. I was observed randomly. Primarily I was removed ```thumbnailLink and WebLink``` since it transfer big URL data. I was reproducing this issue after uploaded 1500files to my drive fiolder. :)

Comment: So if you perform the query `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q='1GV_qAYwU-HYQNeBHcECWfFnaew' in parents and trashed = false&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,createdTime,mimeType,size, trashed)` - it works as intended?

Comment: There are severals [bugs](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760667) related to thumbNailLinks. See if you can isolate the problem and either comment on an existing bug or file a new one on Google's Public Issue Tracker. Just make sure you can isolate the issue correctly to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Yes correct for the fields getting 1000 items... For my code I need some or additional fields.